# How to disconnect a curl connection to proxy server?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, httpie

I use a proxy server in PHP via `curl` or `httpie`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When executing the script, the connection to the proxy server still exists. Thus, if running another script after 3s, the proxy authentication is refused because it has already connected somewhere else.

How can I fully disconnect from the proxy server by `curl_close` to make the proxy available for other scripts?

Comment: does this script take less than 3s to complete, or not? And does your proxy really only accept one concurrent connection per user??

Comment: @ADyson I meant 3s after finishing this script. No, if a connection is established with the server, the second one cannot get connected.

Comment: is that by design? It's very restrictive. curl_close should close the connection from the client's point of view, but whether the server is closing it properly, who knows. Isolate the problem - does the proxy work as expected if you do something involving it via browser?

Comment: @ADyson I assumed this too. That's why I tried `httpie` too., but in either case, the connection remains open until being timeout from the server. For your reference, it is a paid service from nordvpn.

Comment: Is the cURL call sending a "keep-alive" header?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection